# Amazon EC2 Socket connection not being accepted

Tags: amazon-ec2, firewall

I am trying to run a java application on my EC2 instance. The application accepts socket connections on port 54321. If I try and connect to it, it times out. My Security Group is set as:

```
TCP Port (Service)  Source  Action 
21  0.0.0.0/0   Delete 
22 (SSH)    0.0.0.0/0   Delete 
80 (HTTP)   0.0.0.0/0   Delete 
20393   0.0.0.0/0   Delete 
54321   0.0.0.0/0   Delete
```

Is there anything else I need to do?

```
# iptables -nvL
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
# iptables -nvL -t nat
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
#
```

Comment: Is there a firewall running in the instance itself? (Paste the output of `iptables -nvL` and `iptables -nvL -t nat` if you're not sure.)

Comment: @mgorven Added to the question.

Comment: What version of linux is your EC2 instance?  Do you have SELinux installed/enabled?  Not sure if you need to run IPTables since the EC2 firewall can protect you.

Comment: @Joseph are you sure the app is listening to the outside? do a `netstat -tlpn |grep 54321` and see if you see `0.0.0.0:54321` in the output

Answer (score 1):

I've just had this exact same problem. I was running a RHEL instance, and it's been bugging me for a while.

Anyway, the solution, thanks to @mgorven (in the OP comments) for pointing me in the right direction, is to turn off the Linux firewall, thus:

```
[root@myserver ~]$ service iptables stop
```

This will shut the firewall down, but you also need to  ensure that it does not turn itself back on with the next reboot:

```
[root@myserver ~]$ chkconfig iptables off
```

This solved my problems - hopefully it will solve your issue.

HTH